# Categorical Distribution versus Multinomial

Tags: multinomial-distribution, dirichlet-distribution

In the wikipedia article on Categorical Distribution [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_distribution) under "Terminology" it states that care should be taken between Categorical and Multinomial Distributions, with additionally:

> However, conflating the categorical and multinomial distributions can lead to problems. For example, in a Dirichlet-multinomial distribution, which arises commonly in natural language processing models (although not usually with this name) as a result of collapsed Gibbs sampling where Dirichlet distributions are collapsed out of a hierarchical Bayesian model, it is very important to distinguish categorical from multinomial. The joint distribution of the same
>   variables with the same Dirichlet-multinomial distribution has two
>   different forms depending on whether it is characterized as a
>   distribution whose domain is over individual categorical nodes or over
>   multinomial-style counts of nodes in each particular category (similar
>   to the distinction between a set of Bernoulli-distributed nodes and a
>   single binomial-distributed node). Both forms have very
>   similar-looking probability mass functions (PMF's), which both make
>   reference to multinomial-style counts of nodes in a category. However,
>   the multinomial-style PMF has an extra factor, a multinomial
>   coefficient, that is a constant equal to 1 in the categorical-style
>   PMF. Confusing the two can easily lead to incorrect results in
>   settings where this extra factor is not constant with respect to the
>   distributions of interest.

I am still confused of how the extra factor appears in one but not the other, and no example was provided to clarify the paragraph.

Comment: It means that a categorical distribution is a special case of a multinomial distribution. If you look at the documentation of R's rmultinom, you'll see a "size" parameter. If size$=1$, then it's a categorical distribution. If size$\ne 1$, then it is not a categorical distribution.